# Multiplication operator

Tags: scheme, guile

In Scheme * returns the product of its arguments. If called with no arguments it returns 1, or with one argument it returns the argument:

```
(*) => 1
(* 2) => 2
```

What are the semantics of this? How can it return any value? It appears to be implicitly adding an argument of 1 to perform the multiplication. Where is this explained?

This question arose in my mind when coming across the following:

```
(call-with-values * -) => -1
```

Obviously this is because 1 is the identity for multiplication, but I can't quite see this referred to anywhere. In brief, why is the product of no arguments 1?

Comment: Obfuscation, of course. :P

Comment: Note that `and` and `or` work the same way when called with no arguments: `(and)` returns `#t` and `(or)` returns `#f`. Like Alexis's answer says, it makes the language more internally consistent and reduces the corner cases your code has to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a useful property of both `+` and `*`: they both return the identity for their respective operations when called with no arguments. The fact that `(+)` returns `0` instead of simply throwing an error is probably more obviously useful, since it makes the common idiom of summing a list using `(apply + list-of-numbers)` work for the empty list. Similarly, you could use `*` to take the product of all numbers in a list, but this is perhaps less obviously useful.

Still, I think the analogue to `+` is strong enough to argue that the zero-argument behavior of `*` at least *makes sense*. I don’t think that making it throw would prevent all that many bugs, and it might make some useful code harder to write. I think the fact that making it return the identity improves the “smoothness” of the language (it is more internally-consistent) is one of the reasons Scheme feels like such a clean and principled language.